# Why slicing the params hash poses a security issue on mass-assignment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, mass-assignment, strong-parameters

The official way of preventing security risks with mass-assignment is using [attr_accessible](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html). However, some programmers feel this is not a job for the model (or at least not *only* for the model). The simplest way of doing it in a controller is slicing the *params* hash:

```
@user = User.update_attributes(params[:user].slice(:name))
```

However the documentation states:

> Note that using Hash#except or Hash#slice in place of attr_accessible
>   to sanitize attributes won’t provide sufficient protection.

Why is that? **Why a whitelist-slicing of *params* does not provide enough protection?**

**UPDATE:** [Rails 4.0 will ship strong-parameters](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/21/strong-parameters/), a refined slicing of parameters, so I guess the whole slicing thing was not so bad after all.

Comment: Well for starters it's just an inconvenience. With `attr_accesible` you can use `:name` in your model if you need to (albeit it without saving it), but if you `.slice` it off the `params` hash you can't do that. It's also much more semantic to use `attr_accesible` because it tells others the properties relationship with the model, whereas slicing it is much more cryptic.

Comment: @Alex: I understand that *attr_accessible* is a convenient way of managing mass-assignment. Ok, but what's the security hole of using params[:xyz].slice?

Comment: For the record, [attr_accessible](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_accessible) now states "*Note that using Hash#except or Hash#slice in place of attr_accessible to sanitize attributes provides basically the same functionality, but it makes a bit tricky to deal with nested attributes.*" Also, see the [Edge API](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) for advance Rails 4 docs, and see [strong_parameters plugin](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) for what to use prior to Rails 4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with slice and except in controller might occur in combination with `accept_nested_attributes_for` in your model. If you use nested attributes, you would need to slice parameters on all places, where you update them in controller, which isn't always the easiest task, especially with deeply nested scenarios. With using `attr_accesible` you don't have this problem.

Comment: ah, nested attributes, it would be indeed an unpleasant work to filter the `params` in this case.

Answer (score 4):

As of Rails 4, slicing the parameters will be the preferred method of dealing with mass assignment security. The Rails core team has already developed a plugin to deal with this now, and they are working on integrating support for nested attributes and signed forms. Definitely something to check out: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/21/strong-parameters/

Comment: "The basic idea is to move mass-assignment protection out of the model and into the controller where it belongs.". Nice.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting gist from DHH on slicing in controller vs whitelisting alone:

https://gist.github.com/1975644

```
class PostsController < ActionController::Base
  def create
    Post.create(post_params)
  end

  def update
    Post.find(params[:id]).update_attributes!(post_params)
  end

  private
    def post_params
      params[:post].slice(:title, :content)
    end
end
```

Comment reinforcing the need to manage this within the controller:

https://gist.github.com/1975644#gistcomment-88369

I personally apply both - attr_accessible with slice to ensure nothing unexpected gets through. Never rely on blacklisting alone!

Answer (score 2):

Just removing the :name from the params hash works to prevent setting that attribute for that action. It works only for the actions you remember protecting.

However, this practice doesn't protect you from abuse using all the methods automatically added for associations.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end
```

will leave you vulnerable for someone setting the `comments_ids` attribute, even when you delete the `comments` attribute from params.

Since there are quite a lot of methods added for associations, and since they might change in the future, the best practice is to protect your attributes on the model using `attr_accessible`. This will stop these kind of attacks most effectively.

Comment: Hash#slice is used for whitelisting: {:comments_ids => [1,2,3], :name => 'hello'}.slice(:name) #=> {:name=>"hello"}. I really don't see what could possible go wrong with it (dangerous phrase :-))

Comment: Anyway, as I said, I understand why *attr_accessible* is a good way to handle mass-assignment security. But I was curious what was wrong with a slice, what extra security provides *attr_accessible*?

Comment: attr_accessible protects your model in every action, all the time, without you having to remember putting it in each controller.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, all you wrote it's true, but I am not sure that the docs saying "it won’t provide sufficient protection" means "it's not secure because you may forgive to put it".

Comment: I'm with @tokland here - can't understand how *Hash#slice* could be less  secure than *attr_accessible*. And if you forgot about *Hash#slice*... well, then **forgetting** about Hash#slice is insecure, and not the Hash#slice itself.

Comment: Hash#slice would be used to keep specific params, not delete them, so your example doesn't really work

Comment: As of Rails 4, slicing the parameters will become the preferred method to deal with this. http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/21/strong-parameters/

Answer (score 0):

@tokland your last comment is not correct to some extend. Unless your website has the browser as the only entry point where data comes in and goes out.

If your webapp has an API or communicates with other API's protection on the controller level leaves holes behind it and all data from other sources is not sanitised or checked. I recommend keeping the things as they are, turning on **mass-assignment** protection in application.rb and advancing ActiveSupport FormHelpers to work like Django/Python style.

Comment: which one of my comments? I wrote a lot of them in this page :-) Anyway, I don't see the diferrence between having an API or a browser form. Of course the whole point is to avoid the user updating attributes he is not supposed to by tampering attributes.

Comment: @tokland The one where you say "The basic idea is to move mass-assignment protection out of the model and into the controller where it belongs."

Comment: It's a quote from the linked article. But I agree, now I see this as a task for *both* the model and the controller.