# strong_parameters in rails for multiple keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I want to access three keys from params.

Say my params is:

```
params = {
   'product_id' =>  11,
   'category' => {
                   'name' => 'Pet',
                   'sub_categories' => {5 => 'Name1', 7 => 'Name2'} ## **UPDATE**
                   'id' => 100
    },
    'user_action' => 'save'
}
```

Now I want to use strong parameters to filter these key out. i.e

```
#Inside controller
#action
def save_product_category
  product_params[:product_id]
  product_params[:category]
  product_params[:user_action]
end

private
  def product_params
     params.permit(:product_id, :user_action, :category) # Doesn't work, eliminates 'category' key
  end
```

How do I filter out these three keys?

**UPDATE:**
I found one way to do it:

```
params.slice(:product_id, :category, :user_action)
```

Is it right way to do it?

**UPDATE 2:**
Here is the correct answer:

```
params.permit(:product_id, :user_action, :category => [:id, :name, :sub_categories => {}])
```

Thanks @R_O_R and @twonegatives helping me out and bearing with me :)

Answer (score 1):

Well you want

```
def product_params
  params.permit(:product_id, :user_action, category: [ :name, :id ])
end
```

[Nested Parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#nested-parameters)

Comment: No they are not same. While using `slice` you are extracting your desired attributes from `params`, which is another `Hash` object, that you are using to update. But if you want to use directly the `param` object, you need to take the help of the **strong parameter**.

Comment: Agreed. But in updated query, I've updated the parameter required inside 'category'. Can you please check `sub_categories` of `category` of  `params` section of question above?

Comment: @Indyarocks I checked that, and what I said is simply applied again. Just read the linked documentation, and you will get the idea.

Comment: Yea, I went through the link. Thanks. The problem is:
params.permit(:product_id, :user_action, :categories => [:id, :name, :sub_categories => [ ????]]), since the `keys` inside `sub_categories` hash are user input and not specific symbol/string key, how do I whitelist them?

Comment: Got the answer. `params.permit(:product_id, :user_action, :categories => [:id, :name, :sub_categories => {}])` . Thanks.

Comment: @Indyarocks glad you got answers.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should explicitly define all the nested attributes of your parameters:

```
def product_params
  params.permit(:product_id, :user_action, category: [:id, :name] )
end
```

Reference to [Rails 4 Strong parameters nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436741/rails-4-strong-parameters-nested-objects)

**UPDATE**

As of your question about `slice`, well, that usage is possible aswell. Long story short, back in 2012 people used Rails 3 which did not provide any way of filtering incoming params in controller, so `slice` method was used for that purpose. Some references to that time can be even found here on stackoverflow (see [slicing on mass assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483451/why-slicing-the-params-hash-poses-a-security-issue-on-mass-assignment)) and on github (here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/dhh/1975644) from DHH, creator of Ruby on Rails). At the end of the day, `strong parameters` gem is simply an extraction of the `slice` pattern. But for now it would be more convenient to follow `permit` pattern for Rails 4.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a note on `slice` method.

Comment: I've updated the parameter required inside 'category'. Can you please check sub_categories of category of params section of question above? Please refer comments of previous answer.

Comment: @Indyarocks you should pay more attention to the links people route you to. this answer addresses exactly the last of your problems (could be found at Rails 4 strong params thread which I posted above):
http://stackoverflow.com/a/24475600/1276552

Comment: Got the answer. `params.permit(:product_id, :user_action, :categories => [:id, :name, :sub_categories => {}])` . Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @twonegatives. In the link the answer had specific keys defined for `sub_categories`.
`params.require(:foo).permit(:bar, {:baz => [:x, :y]})` `:x` and `:y`. I wanted to allow the complete hash. Anyways, apologies for not putting up my query clearly in first place. Thanks!